# How to open Activity with Notification preserving your actual state Without call the create method

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have one app that I need keep your cycle, and when I use the click action of the notification the activity restart. How can I call the get Pending Intent without needing to go through create method of the activity and go straight to the resume? This my notification Builder:

```
private fun createIntermediaryNotification(context: Context){
    val resultIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run{
        addNextIntent(resultIntent)
        getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
    }
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle("Pomodoro App")
        .setContentText("Let's Start New Break !")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).apply {
        notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
    }
}
```

I'm using a sequence of states linked to its ViewModel, such as a Pomodoro App, where after a cycle the next cycle has a different duration and vice versa. So I need that when I click on the notification an intent is not created, but the current one is maintained.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. An Activity is always created with an Intent. That Intent it was created with cannot be changed. I don't think you can somehow deliver a different Intent to an existing Activity instance.

Comment: It sounds like you should be persisting your data to disk and not relying on your activity instance to be the source of truth.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand, in this case I will have to do this management in a shared preferences and retrieve it at the start of the activity